# Masstransit Filter with IoC injection/Database

Tags: c#, autofac, masstransit

I have to validate incoming message before passing it to my consumer.
To do it, I need to request some data from the database.

Following the tutorials, I created extension method to apply my specification + filter to the consumer pipe. Something like this:

```
public static void UseArticlesImportValidation(this IConsumePipeConfigurator configurator){}

public class ArticlesImportValidationSpecification : IPipeSpecification<ConsumeContext<ArticlesImportNotification>>
```

and the Filter

```
public class ArticlesImportValidationFilter : IFilter<ConsumeContext<ArticlesImportNotification>>
```

Everything looks good, but I want to injection some business services in my Filter to reuse some functionality + DAL services. This works completely fine for my Consumer using Autofac extension method `builder.RegisterConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`.

Should I use middleware for this at all? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the built container in your specification (it is easy to pass as a parameter when you call `AddPipeSpecification` and then in the specification:

```
public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<T> builder)
{
    builder.AddFilter(new ArticlesImportValidationFilter(container.Resolve<IDataAccessSomethingUseful>()));
}
```

But I would validate in the consumer or, if you want to keep them separate, have one consumer to validate and send the next message to do the actual job.

Comment: That's what I eventually did, what is the reason to make validation inside the consumer? or with two consumers? won't it complicate the flow of the messages in general?

Comment: It depends (tm). In my solution I implement CQRS and I need to send a valid command to my domain model. This means that the sender must pre-validate the stuff. In case I have some untrusted sender, I introduce an intermediate step for such validation but since it is not for everyone, it would be overkill to run this validation always. Therefore, I slip it. Also, when validation fails, what would you do? If you have a consumer - you can send a message back saying "go away" and this is a good practice.

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov there is a similar thing on github issues https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/737, may be it will help too.

Comment: This solution does make a singleton out of the requested resource. Is there also a way to access the scoped container INSIDE the filter's `Send()` method?

Comment: You can see example of access to scoped container here: https://github.com/F0b0s/MassTransit.UnitOfWork

Answer (score 1):

You should use Scoped Filters in this situation

Let's say you have a filter with dependency

```
public class MyConsumeFilter<T> :
    IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>
    where T : class
{
    public MyConsumeFilter(IMyDependency dependency) { }
      
    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next) { }
      
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }
}
```

you should register this dependency in your DI container

```
services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>(); //register dependency
```

And now you are ready to add this filter to the consumer pipe by calling `UseConsumeFilter` method:

```
services.AddConsumer<MyConsumer>();
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("input-queue", e =>
                {
                    e.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyConsumeFilter<>), context); //generic filter

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<MyConsumer>();
                });
            });
        });
```